# How to escape the character "?" in For..Do in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using this code to set some data into array but, i'm stuck on echoing the last one who has this character `"?"`
So; my question is how can i escape this kind of character `"?"` to echo the last item like `"Hackoo?"`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
for %%a in ("1" "2" "223231" "AAA" "Hello^ | World" "(Hello^)(World^)" "Hackoo^?") do (
set /a i+=1
  set Line[!i!]="%%~a"
)
set Line
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FOR` without any switch the `CMD` will try to get a path if your using the special char `?`.

A solution is the substitution if you can't use any other switch (like : `/F`) :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set $List="1" "2" "223231" "AAA" "Hello | World" "(Hello)(World)" "Hackoo ?"
set $List=%$List:?=#%

set i=0
for %%a in (%$List%) do (
set /a i+=1
  set "$Tmp=%%a"
  set "Line[!i!]=!$Tmp:#=?!"
)
set Line
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in ("? * ; %%") do (
    echo %%a
    echo %%b
    echo %%c
    echo %%d
)
pause
```